# SQL Server Compact Database File

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server Compact Database file (`.sdf`) that I am trying to connect through using Visual Studio 2017. I have installed SQLight / SQL Server Compact ToolBox with NuGetPackage Manager.

I have placed a `SqlDataSource` on the ASPX page.

I click new "Connection" Select "SQL Server Compact 4.0 (Simple by ErikEJ)"

Put in the Data Source.

Test Connection "Test connection succeeded".

Click OK and I get this error

> Exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Data.InternalException' was thrown

I have searched google can not find anything about this. I can connect to different SQL Server databases but not to this `.sdf`.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

SqlDataSource does not work with SQL Server Compact (or vice versa). Use for example EF Core or ADO.NET for data access instead.